# I want to create a movement app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an app, but I am not able to make the "man" able to run and jump(as temple run)
I have created the first part of the app, but I don't know how to add this function

```
package com.francesco.provadinuovo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent MainActivity3;
    Button button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        button3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I wanted to write: image1 can move or jump and if touch something the game end

Comment: What image1? I think we need to know more of your code to help you, see [ask].

Comment: ok, i'll do that, image1 is a "man" but it is only an image of man...how could I make it able to jump? sorry but i am new in programming

Answer (score 1):

What you apparently want is an animation, you should check out these links ->

General animation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

Translate animation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

Here is some example code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
TranslateAnimation jumper = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
jumper.setDuration(1000); // animation duration in milliseconds
jumper.setFillAfter(true); // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
if (image != null) {
    image.startAnimation(jumper);
}
```

Comment: how can i do it?